# List Distinct elements including a count with Java Streams

Tags: java, count, java-stream, distinct

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a single Java Steam statement to print out the unique elements in a collection and include the count for each element.

For example, if I had:

```
List<String> animals = Arrays.asList("dog", "cat", "pony", "pony", "pony", "dog");
```

I'd want the stream to print:

```
cat - 1
dog - 2
pony - 3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<String, Long> result = animals.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group the elements with the same key. Then apply the `counting` down stream collector for each group to get the count.

Comment: I wonder how it's returning map keys in sorted order. Think its coincidence? If not then explanation would really help.

Comment: It's depending on the hash function used, which is implementation specific. However it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Comment: No, `TreeMap` is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys. Here it is just a `HashMap`

Answer (score 6):

You can combine a grouping and a counting collector:

```
Map<String, Long> countMap = Arrays.asList("dog", "cat", "pony", "pony", "pony", "dog")
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
```

And that results in this map:

```
{cat=1, dog=2, pony=3}
```

Comment: I really wonder when I have the ability to use streams efficiently like you +1

Comment: @snr Just use them often :-) - (they're fun)

Comment: @ernest_k I wonder how it's returning map keys in sorted order. Think its coincidence?  If not then explanation would really help.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik Yes, you shouldn't count on that. The returned type in this case is a `HashMap`. If you need it to be ordered, then you should collect differently in order to specify an ordered `Map` class